# No mostrar registros duplicados de entrada de la misma fecha

Tags: mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es sistema de asistencia de personal y el personal registra entrada y salida, ocasionalmente el usuario registra dos entradas el mismo día, he creado una consulta en mysql para un reporte de Excel y necesito contar los registros del ultimo mes que dicen entradas, pero me cuenta los registros duplicados del mismo día.

```
SELECT 
cedula, COUNT(*)  
FROM marcados  
WHERE tipo='entrada' AND fecha >= NOW() - INTERVAL (DAY(NOW())-0) DAY  
GROUP BY cedula
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, usa el boton [edit] y deja la pregunta completa.. que es ese sql? que es una entrada duplicada?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas son registros duplicados de una cédula en un mismo día, así que debes incluir la fecha en la agrupación. Para que solo aparezcan los duplicados puedes utilizar el `HAVING`:

```
SELECT cedula, fecha, COUNT(*)  
FROM marcados  
WHERE tipo='entrada' 
GROUP BY cedula, fecha
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

En tu caso concreto para el día de hoy, evitaríamos la agrupación por fecha

```
SELECT cedula, COUNT(*)  
FROM marcados  
WHERE tipo='entrada' 
AND fecha >= NOW() - INTERVAL (DAY(NOW())-0) DAY
GROUP BY cedula
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Para los de este mes:

```
SELECT cedula, fecha, COUNT(*)  
FROM marcados  
WHERE tipo='entrada' 
AND YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY cedula, fecha
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: gracias, pero si requiero ver todos los registros del ultimo mes es decir del 1 febrero hasta hoy?

Comment: He editado la respuesta para incluir solo los de este mes

Comment: Eso era. gracias Roger.